# Email from UNIX change the color of specific variable

Tags: html, email, unix

I am checking the space of a UNIX server daily and i send an email with the current space. What i want to do is change the color of the "SPACE" variable to red when i am printing it.

```
 echo "Server extends the limit, the data is at: " $SPACE% | mailx -r
 Panos@mail.com -s "Data_Usage" George@mail.com
```

I tried the

```
tput setaf 1; echo "this is red text"
```

EDIT

The only way is with html. Unix only change the font color on terminal.

Here is the code i wrote.

```
echo "Subject: Atlas1 space ";
                 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                 echo "Content-Type: text/html";
                 echo "Content-Disposition: inline";
                 echo "<body> <p style=\"font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color:black\">";
                 echo "<b> The space at Atlas is more than: <font color="red"> 70%</font> the auto delition will be activated </b>";
                 echo "</p> <pre>"              
                 echo "</pre>"
                 echo "<br>"
                 echo "<p style=\"font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color:black\">";
                 echo "Now the space is at<font color="red">  $SPACE% </font>"
                 echo "</p> </body>"; ) | /usr/sbin/sendmail `cat $MAILLST`
```

Many thanks,
Panos

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct about using html. Are you facing any problem with that?

Comment: Yes, the only way is with html, Otherwise the unix change the color font on terminal only.check above my edit. NO problem at all.